# What happens if I romance Kaidan as a male Shepard in ME1 by editing save file and import the save file to ME2 and ME3?

Tags: mass-effect-series

As said in the title, I want to romance Kaidan in the first game. Since it isn't possible in a normal play, I'm afraid the save file may get corrupted so I can't play my old Shepard if I import it into ME2 and ME3; or it can be imported but their relationship is gone. Maybe Bioware didn't prepare the lines for such scenario and they say something strange when they reunite. If any of these situations happen, I think I would consider delaying the romance until the third game.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the mod you want to use?

Comment: There isn't a mod, I think I will edit my save file to romance Kaidan in ME1. [link](http://forum.bioware.com/topic/116127-female-shepard-romancing-ashley/) (I misunderstood when I saw someone on Youtube said they modded the game. Will fix my question accordingly later.)

Comment: Ah, okay. Take out the mods tag when you edit, then. The link you provided has two methods, using `SetGender` and Hex Editing your savegame. Which one would you use, as this might have an influence on the result

Comment: I would use Hex Editing.

Comment: Is there anything to stop you backing up the file, making the modifications and seeing if you can import it successfully?

Comment: as far as i know, male Shepard can't romance Kaidan in ME1 as he is still straight. but if you're using a mod to make him available to be romanced in ME1.

Comment: If you use console commands you can switch genders and some things work/play as the first gender, and others as the second gender. So my guess is that you'll get a mix of some of the conversations applying to the new situation and some applying to the original gender settings/choices. My guess is that it won't crash, it just may choose or play some of the 'wrong' conversations or NPCs.

Comment: Please clarify "I want to romance Kaidan in the first game. But since it isn't possible in a normal play..." Because if you are female you can romance Kaiden in normal play. Do you mean you can't romance him after you've chosen male normally and then altered your save file to be female? If so, I wouldn't consider that 'normal play.'

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a love interest related dialog comes up you will get the same dialog female/male Sheppard would get. This usually happens if you edit romances via save game editors that are gender exclusive like Kaidan who used to be exclusively for female player characters